# How to run multiple Rails unit tests at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit

I often run the various test groups like:

```
rake test:units
rake test:functionals
```

I also like to run individual test files or individual tests:

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/file_test.rb
ruby -Itest test/unit/file_test.rb -n '/some context Im working on/'
```

There's also:

```
rake test TEST=test/unit/file_test.rb
```

And I've even created custom groupings in my Rakefile:

```
  Rake::TestTask.new(:ps3) do |t|
    t.libs << 'test'
    t.verbose = true
    t.test_files = FileList["test/unit/**/ps3_*_test.rb", "test/functional/services/ps3/*_test.rb"]
  end
```

What I haven't figured out yet is how to run multiple ad-hoc tests at the command line.  In other words, how can I inject test_files into the rake task.  Something like:

```
rake test TEST=test/unit/file_test.rb,test/functional/files_controller_test.rb
```

Then I could run a shell function taking arbitrary parameters and run the fast `ruby -Itest` single test, or a `rake` task if there's more than one file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up hacking this into my RakeFile myself like so:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:fast) do |t|
  files = if ENV['TEST_FILES']
    ENV['TEST_FILES'].split(',')
  else
    FileList["test/unit/**/*_test.rb", "test/functional/**/*_test.rb", "test/integration/**/*_test.rb"]
  end

  t.libs << 'test'
  t.verbose = true
  t.test_files = files
end
Rake::Task['test:fast'].comment = "Runs unit/functional/integration tests (or a list of files in TEST_FILES) in one block"
```

Then I whipped up this bash function that allows you to call `rt` with an arbitrary list of test files.  If there's just one file it runs it as ruby directly (this saves 8 seconds for my 50k loc app), otherwise it runs the rake task.

```
function rt {
  if [ $# -le 1 ] ; then
    ruby -Itest $1
  else
    test_files = ""
    while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
      if [ "$test_files" == "" ]; then
        test_files=$1
      else
        test_files="$test_files,$1"
      fi
      shift
    done
    rake test:fast TEST_FILES=$test_files
  fi
}
```

Comment: thanks dasil003 for pointing the Rake::TestTask class, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 17):

```
bundle exec ruby -I.:test -e "ARGV.each{|f| require f}" file1 file1
```

or:

```
find test -name '*_test.rb' | xargs -t bundle exec ruby -I.:test -e "ARGV.each{|f| require f}"
```

Comment: Also you may want to replace `ruby` with `ruby -w` in both those examples.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [parallel_tests gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) that will let you run multiple tests in parallel.  Once you have it in your Gemfile, you can just run as ...

```
bundle exec parallel_test integration/test_*.rb
```

For me I setup a short rake task to run only the tests I want.

Comment: bundle exec -n0 parallel_test integration/test_*.rb
to run them without parallelisation

Comment: it is not -n0 it is -n1

Comment: Super useful way if you are __already__ using this gem to run tests in parallel some times (in CI, for instance) but still go to regular `rake test` in development to run some tests just as the matter of habbit, as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash Script

```
RUBY_MULTI_TEST="/tmp/ruby_multi_test.rb"

function suitup-multi-test-prepare {
  sudo rm $RUBY_MULTI_TEST 2> /dev/null
}

function suitup-multi-test-add {
  WORK_FOLDER=`pwd`
  echo "require '$WORK_FOLDER/$1' " >> $RUBY_MULTI_TEST
}

function suitup-multi-test-status {
  cat $RUBY_MULTI_TEST 2> /dev/null
}

function suitup-multi-test-run {
  suitup-multi-test-status
  ruby -I test/ $RUBY_MULTI_TEST
}

ery@tkpad:rails_app:$ suitup-multi-test-prepare
ery@tkpad:rails_app:$ suitup-multi-test-add test/functional/day_reports_controller_test.rb
ery@tkpad:rails_app:$ suitup-multi-test-add test/functional/month_reports_controller_test.rb
ery@tkpad:rails_app:$ suitup-multi-test-run
```